# Libusb on Ubuntu

Tags: libusb

I use libusb to make a program to read data from USB devices on ubuntu 11:04. Why, when multiple programs to read data from usb, only a new program activation is executed while the remaining programs are not continued implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because each program is trying to claim the device interface (similar to a program opening and locking a file so that other processes cannot at the samme time edit the file).